# Prove: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+a}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+b}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+c}} \leq \sqrt{3}$, given $a + b + c = abc - 2$

Tags: inequality

We are given that a, b, and c are positive real numbers such that:

$a + b + c = abc - 2$

We want to prove the following inequality:

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+b}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+c}} \leq \sqrt{3}$

**Can anyone provide a proof for this inequality under the condition that a, b, and c are positive?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Consider that many users in this forum won't even read your questions if they're not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Comment: I had a go at fixing your formatting. Please advise whether or not this is correct or not (it was difficult to tell the way you asked the question).

Comment: @RedFive thanks alot. It's correct

Comment: All good. I'm working on a few other problems right now, but intend to get to yours soon. It is likely that someone will beat me to the answer though - there are A LOT of really clever commenters on this site!

Comment: @RedFive Please don't answer "no-effort" questions.

Comment: @RedFive Chances are the question will get closed before you get to it. (If it doesn’t get edited.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I’m so sorry to hear that. I am currently 40 years old, and I’m working on this problem with my daughter. Unfortunately, due to my limited English proficiency, I find it challenging to provide a more detailed explanation of my work. However, I have attempted to apply the AM-GM inequality. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: You could try the same substitute as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143537/how-prove-this-inequality-with-abc2-abc).

Comment: Judging from your comment, your English is better than mine. So why don't you start working on it and include your tryings? Did you try to read other posts about the same topic? Why not?

Comment: OK @Alg, I will work on it off -site as it looks like it has been scheduled for closure.

Comment: @ĐặngHảiĐăng - with your permission, I'm going to have a go at re-writing this question and posting it again. If that happens, it will appear under my own question list.

Comment: @RedFive I think, you should go for it. The OP didn’t edit their question, so they probably lost interest in it. The question is interesting and deserves a proper post. For example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4885163/find-the-radius-of-the-circle-tangent-to-x2-sqrtx-x-2) was created by another user less than an hour after the original question was closed.